# Full screen is not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

Full screen is working in chrome and other browsers but not working in Safari. Here is my code:

```js
var doc = window.document;
var docEl = document.getElementById("divId");      
//doc.documentElement;

var requestFullScreen = docEl.requestFullscreen || docEl.mozRequestFullScreen || docEl.webkitRequestFullScreen || docEl.msRequestFullscreen;
var cancelFullScreen = doc.exitFullscreen || doc.mozCancelFullScreen || doc.webkitExitFullscreen || doc.msExitFullscreen;

if(!doc.fullscreenElement && !doc.mozFullScreenElement && !doc.webkitFullscreenElement && !doc.msFullscreenElement){
  requestFullScreen.call(docEl);
} else { 
  cancelFullScreen.call(doc);
}
```

```html
<div id="divId" style="width: 300px;height:60px" > FULL SCREEN </div>
```

Answer (score 10):

It is `Element.webkitRequestFullscreen`, lower-case `s` in Full**s**creen.
Only Firefox did set their vendor-prefixed version with a camel-cased *FullScreen*, <sup><sub>probably to make everyone's life harder...</sub></sup>

```js
var requestFullScreen = docEl.requestFullscreen || docEl.webkitRequestFullscreen || docEl.mozRequestFullScreen ||  docEl.msRequestFullscreen;
```

[As a fiddle since StackSnippets' iframes don't allow fullscreen](https://jsfiddle.net/L4x85pq1/)

Comment: Thanks, but not working

Comment: One thing, your js fiddle code also not opening in safari.

Comment: @GuruduttSharma which version? Works for me on 11

Comment: Safari version in my machine is 5.1.7. My machine OS is window 7.

Comment: Stop using it right now! The last update was made in 2015, it has a lot of security breaches that won't get fixed ever. And moreover, it has nothing to do with recent versions. If you want to test your website on Safari, do it from macOS (be it in a VM)

Comment: Okay, Thanks @Kaiido

Answer (score 9):

The Fullscreen API is **not supported in iOS Safari** and has **partial support in Safari**: **[more on this](https://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen)**.

I would recommend to check out **Sindre's cross-browser wrapper**, **[screenfull.js](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js)** around the Fullscreen API, at least **[check out the source](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/blob/gh-pages/src/screenfull.js)** and get what your current project needs.

If you create a **web app**, that your users will install, **[here you can find out more about certain meta tags](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/)** to specify in order to run your web app in full-screen.

Comment: I'm using full screen functionality in angularJS web application. I have tried screenfull.js (https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js). Same this is working in chrome  but not working in safari.

Comment: Do you have any [error messages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/onfullscreenerror), when requesting full screen in Safari?

Comment: Yes, In console two error message are:

file://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js The requested URL was not found on this server.

file://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: I have removed these files from code but code is not working in safari. I think, this can be a safari browser configuration issue.